# how to fix this notice error

Tags: php

I have an unexpected ; error on this line:

$action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? 'create_session2.php';

But if I remove the ; then it states unexpected { in the line below, how can this be sorted out?

below full code:

```
if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){

    $action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? 'create_session2.php';

}else if($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){

    $action = ($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the ternary operator, you need to have values for when the condition is both TRUE and FALSE:

```
$action = ($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] : "false";
```

I am not sure why you are doing the checks twice, the following should suffice:

```
<?php 
if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = 'create_session2.php'; 

}else($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

}
```

Comment: Actually the second `if` statement can be removed.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: I seem to have over looked that. Answer edited :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a short if statement: `[condition] ? [if_true] : [if_false]`

but the `: [if_false]` part is missing

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operation requires that you add an alternative if the condition is not true (instead it is false):

```
$action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? 'create_session2.php' : 'was_false';
```

Psuedo looks like:

```
$variable = ($condition == true) ? true : false;
```

You can read more about comparison operators (and ternary) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot **else** command

```
$action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? 'create_session2.php':'';
```

Answer (score 0):

All of you code can be rewritten as:

```
$action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? 'create_session2.php' : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Have fun.

Comment: I tried this way first but it did not perform the actions  I wanted

Comment: @user1292857, that's exactly what your original code do, man.

Comment: yep before the code I mentioned in my question I did it exactly the same way you did it, the problem was that if there was a match, then it works fine, but I never stated what happened if there wasn't a match, I thought the : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] would do it but it didn't

Comment: @user1292857, then the problem lay in your application, not in our answers :). Be cool.